# Почему else меняет выполнение условия?

Tags: javascript

Задача заключается в том, что пользователь вводит свой язык и ему должно вернуться приветствие на его языке. Если такого языка нет, то должно выводиться приветствие на английском языке.
Проблема заключается в том, что в конструкции if else, когда проверяю на наличие такого языка, когда добавляю else, то все языки выводят приветствие на английском. Если оставить if, то все работает.

Почему else меняет выполнение условия?

```js
function greet(language) {
    const userLangue = language.toLowerCase();

    const languages = {
        english: 'Welcome',
        czech: 'Vitejte',
        danish: 'Velkomst',
        dutch: 'Welkom',
        estonian: 'Tere tulemast',
        finnish: 'Tervetuloa',
        flemish: 'Welgekomen',
        french: 'Bienvenue',
        german: 'Willkommen',
        irish: 'Failte',
        italian: 'Benvenuto',
        latvian: 'Gaidits',
        lithuanian: 'Laukiamas',
        polish: 'Witamy',
        spanish: 'Bienvenido',
        swedish: 'Valkommen',
        welsh: 'Croeso'
    }

    for(let lang in languages){
        if(userLangue === lang){
            return languages[userLangue];
        } else {
            return languages.english;
        } // если убрать elsе, то будет работать правильно   
    }

}

console.log(greet('english'));
console.log(greet('dutch'));
console.log(greet('polish'));
```

При том, что если язык есть, то должно выполняться конструкция, которая лежит в if, но выполняется конструкция, которая лежит в else.

Comment: У Вас else выполняется при КАЖДОЙ проверке. А сперва Вы проверяете на аглицкий. Так что независимо от языка - получаете аглицкий (если нужен он - то через if, иначе через его else). Аглицкий для неизвестного языка должен выбираться только если for полностью отработал, но языка не нашёл. Уберите else и поместите только return после for(){}: `for(let lang in languages){
        if(userLangue === lang){
            return languages[userLangue];
        }
            return languages.english;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все потому что, у вас есть конструкция return, которая прерывает не цикл, а всю фунцию. Поэтому если в первой итерации мы не получаем совпадение, то возвращаем `english`, что у вас и происходит. Для решения можно воспользоваться немного другим способом:

```js
function greet(language) {
    const userLangue = language.toLowerCase();

    const languages = {
        english: 'Welcome',
        czech: 'Vitejte',
        danish: 'Velkomst',
        dutch: 'Welkom',
        estonian: 'Tere tulemast',
        finnish: 'Tervetuloa',
        flemish: 'Welgekomen',
        french: 'Bienvenue',
        german: 'Willkommen',
        irish: 'Failte',
        italian: 'Benvenuto',
        latvian: 'Gaidits',
        lithuanian: 'Laukiamas',
        polish: 'Witamy',
        spanish: 'Bienvenido',
        swedish: 'Valkommen',
        welsh: 'Croeso'
    }

    for(let lang in languages){
        // Если мы нашли совпадение, то возвращаем его.
        // Если не нашли, то продолжаем идти по циклу.
        if(userLangue === lang){
            return languages[userLangue];
        }  
    }
    // И только после всего цикла, если мы до сих пор не вышли из функции
    // Значит совпадений нет, можно вернут значение по умолчанию.
    return languages.english;

}

console.log(greet('english'));
console.log(greet('dutch'));
console.log(greet('polish'));
console.log(greet('klingon'));
```

Answer (score 3):

потому что выходит сразу после первой итерации.

```js
function greet(language) {
    const userLangue = language.toLowerCase();

    const languages = {
        english: 'Welcome',
        czech: 'Vitejte',
        danish: 'Velkomst',
        dutch: 'Welkom',
        estonian: 'Tere tulemast',
        finnish: 'Tervetuloa',
        flemish: 'Welgekomen',
        french: 'Bienvenue',
        german: 'Willkommen',
        irish: 'Failte',
        italian: 'Benvenuto',
        latvian: 'Gaidits',
        lithuanian: 'Laukiamas',
        polish: 'Witamy',
        spanish: 'Bienvenido',
        swedish: 'Valkommen',
        welsh: 'Croeso'
    }

     return languages[userLangue] || languages.english;
}

console.log(greet('english'));
console.log(greet('dutch'));
console.log(greet('polish'));
```